# How can I make an array of one table's column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make an array of all numbers. Here is my code:

```js
$(function(){ // dom ready
    $('tr').each(function() {
      var nums = $(this).map(function() {
          return (this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text()
      }).get();
      console.log(nums);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>760</td>
        <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>532</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>201</td>
        <td>Martin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Barman</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What's wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Comment: add `$` at line 4 of your js, before `(this).find`

Comment: you forgot $ sign in return..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you're missing a `$` prefix on the `(this)` in the `map()` handler. Then to get the numbers use `:nth-child(1)`, not `:nth-child(3)`. Also you can just use `map()` directly, no need for `each()`. Finally, assuming you want the values to actually be numerical and not strings, use `parseInt()` on them, like this:

```js
$(function() { // dom ready
  var nums = $('tr').map(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text(), 10)
  }).get();
  console.log(nums);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>760</td>
      <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>532</td>
      <td>Peter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>201</td>
      <td>Martin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Barman</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like this `parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text())`.`parseInt()` its used to change the string to number

> **Whats Wrong?**
>
> 1. Missing `$`in return statement
> 2. And `numbers` column is a first cell `find('td:nth-child(1)')`
> 3. But you are trying to create a array with `3rd` cell .but is not there.only two column is available

```js
$(function(){ // dom ready
    $('tr').each(function() {
      var nums = $(this).map(function() {
          return parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text())
      }).get();
      console.log(nums);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>760</td>
        <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>532</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>201</td>
        <td>Martin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Barman</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Small Mistake,

change  `return (this).find('td:nth-child(3)')` to `return $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)')`

```js
$(function(){ // dom ready
    $('tr').each(function() {
      var nums = $(this).map(function() {
          return $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text()
      }).get();
      console.log(nums);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>760</td>
        <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>532</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>201</td>
        <td>Martin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Barman</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is ist a 'lighter' version:

```
var nums=[];
$('td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
    nums.push(parseInt(this.innerHTML));
});
console.log(nums);
//[760, 532, 201, 12]
```